# How to load `.env` from another folder?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, .env

How in Next.js to load environment variables from `../.env` instead of `./.env`?

I put my Next.js app to subdirectory `main/` and run it as `cd main && next start`. This forces me to have two copies of `.env`: for Next.js and for Express.js backend component.